# HOW TO: View Redis Data inside Rails application (using Soulmate)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, redis

I am new with ruby on rails.

Currently I am using Redis/Soulmate for an autocomplete feature. I am starting up a new loader and putting in my appointments model like so:

```
loader = Soulmate::Loader.new("appointments")
puts loader.inspect
```

I get the output:

```
#<Soulmate::Loader:0x007fdca25bd840 @type="appointments">
```

But if i begin adding to the loader like so:

```
loader.add("term"=>"randomappointment", "id"=>1)
```

HOW do i  view the output of this command inside my rails application - I want to see the data that I have just input inside the loader (the soulmate hash). I am trying something like this, but nothing is working:

```
puts soulmate-data:appointments 1 or 
puts soulmate-data["appointments"]
```

NOTE: I can do this in my terminal using

```
$ redis-cli
hget soulmate-data:appointments 1
```

which gives the output:

```
"{\"term\":\"randomappointment\",\"id\":1}"
```

Any Ideas? Im using Redis 2.8.19, Rails 4.1.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, i did this using the Soulmate::Matcher class like so:

```
term = "randomappointment" 
result = Soulmate::Matcher.new("appointments").matches_for_term(term)
```